# Где создать тёмную карту для сайта?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Требуется на сайт вставить тёмную карту. Раньше такое можно было сделать через google map API, теперь как я понял использование API подразумевает обязательную привязку к банковской карте, чего разумеется делать не хочется. Яндекс API как я понял такой функции не поддерживает. Как быть? (

Важно, что бы была возможность вставить свой маркер. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону OSM. Я так понял на неё можно накрутить тему. Вот что гугл показал: https://openmaptiles.org/styles/

Answer (score 3):

Заходите в этот [**сайт**](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

Нажимаете `create-style`.Выбираете темный **(dark)** режим как показано внизу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сайт сгенерирует JSON для этого стиля и код для подключение google maps.

```
<div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945},
          zoom: 12,
          styles: [{
               // Стили скопировать сюда ...
          }]
        });
      }
    </script>
<script src="второй код с API_KEY сюда" async defer></script>
```

Можно также взять все готовое  [**отсюда**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/style-array) добавив только API ключ

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать переопределить тему подложки так:

```
[class*="ymaps-2"][class*="-ground-pane"] {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}
```

Но это конечно же немного костыльный вариант.
http://jsfiddle.net/x9o7ksqd/

Свои маркеры вставляются так: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1

Comment: А ночной режим сымитировать возможно таким вариантом?

Comment: Попробуйте) Я лишь показываю направление.

Answer (score 0):

Или так:

```
filter: grayscale(1) invert(100%);
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).